# Consequences of changing an existing model to a polymorphic one in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called "attachments" which belongs to a "quote". Another model "order" is supposed to have 2 type of attachments, "quote_attachments" and "order_attachments".

Since the attachments are already embedded into the "quote", I don't want to have to change what it's called throughout all the "quote" files.

Can I change it into a polymorphic relationship while still using it as a non-polymorphic object?

I realize this is a bad practice but it's only a workaround until the next version is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) are meant for exactly this use case where one model belongs to two models. i.e. Attachments belong to Quotes and Orders.

I would make a migration to turn attachment into a polymorphic model. I linked you to the documentation, so it should be easy to make the change. Make sure to remove any columns that you no longer need in the migration.